# QGIS - Mapping Ward Areas into Thiessen Polygons

Tags: qgis, voronoi, watershed

I am designing a water supply distribution network. I have various pipes represented by Lines. Each start and end point of Line is a Junction (Node).
I have created Thiessen Polygons (Voronoi) using QGIS for each Junction (The Thiessen Polygon represents flow area for its corresponding Junction.)
I also have various Ward Boundaries (also represented as irregular Polygons), with each Ward having different Population.

My requirement : I want to calculate area of intersection between each Thiessen Polygon and each Ward and get a table, so that I can calculate the exact population within each Thiessen Polygon.

**Example of Thiessen Polygons** (The Dot within polygon represents corresponding Junction) :-
[image]

**Example of Wards** (also represented as Closed Polygons) :-

[image]

**Final output desired** :-

[image]

Comment: I have tried to use in QGIS : Vector -> Geo Processing Tools -> Intersection, but I get following error :- "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'difference' See log for more details"

Comment: You may get more traction over at the [GIS stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/), where there are many QGIS users.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in ARCGIS -> Intersect Tool where it intersects Two Shapefiles (each having multiple polygons) and gives intersection results.
I think the same is not possible in QGIS as of now.